# Form not staying ontop and messagebox corrupted

Tags: autoit, labview

We are using AutoIT and Labview 2011 to control an application. Labview is meant to sit ontop and the second application in the background (so the user does not see it)
We have labview set as topmost and have applied windows properties to make it topmost.
However even though labview is topmost we get the background application flickering and say if labview opens a popup message it is blacked out such that if you click on the windows some of it appears after each click.
I dont know what to do. We have spent a few days now trying to fix. The OS is windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I think it is an AutoIT problem, do you call AutoIT from LabView? If so can you show the code?

Comment: Yes I do. I "solved" the issue by showing the messagebox , immediately hiding it for 2 seconds and then shwoing it again. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

"solved" the issue by showing the messagebox , immediately hiding it for 2 seconds and then shwoing it again. Weird.